# Error Messages that Appear Wrong in JavaScript/HTML/Freemarker to Print to PDF

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I've got to make a template for NetSuite to print in PDF and it keeps throwing error codes that appear to be wrong. For example, it will tell me  needs to be inside  when it clearly is inside the pdf tags. I think there might be something else wrong but I can't find it. I am new to JavaScript, and I went to a validator which told me

Unexpected `<`. <#if results?size != 0><#list results as result>.

Not sure where in this phrase `<` is placed incorrectly. Here's the code, it's short, since it is only a test template. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd"><pdfset><#if results?size != 0><#list results as result>
<pdf>
<head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="${nsfont.NotoSans_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSans_Bold}" src-italic="${nsfont.NotoSans_Italic}" src-bolditalic="${nsfont.NotoSans_BoldItalic}" bytes="2" />
    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKsc" type="font" subtype="opentype" 
src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Regular}" src- 
bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
         <link name="NotoSansCJKtc" type="font" subtype="opentype" 
src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Regular}" src- 
bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKjp" type="font" subtype="opentype" 
src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Regular}" src- 
bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKkr" type="font" subtype="opentype" 
src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Regular}" src- 
bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
        <link name="NotoSansThai" type="font" subtype="opentype" 
src="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Bold}" 
bytes="2" />
    </#if>
<style type="text/css">* {
                    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
                        font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKsc, sans-serif;
                    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
                        font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKtc, sans-serif;
                    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
                        font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKjp, sans-serif;
                    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
                        font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKkr, sans-serif;
                    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
                        font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansThai, sans-serif;
                    <#else>
                        font-family: NotoSans, sans-serif;
                    </#if>
                }
                td p { align:left }
</style>
</head>
    <body padding="0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in" size="Letter">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;"> 
    <tr>
    <td>(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, <#if myOptionalVar?? 
>${record.custrecord_test_date_bil}<#else>{}</#if>(myOptionalVar.foo)?? 
    </td></td>
    <td>(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, <#if myOptionalVar?? 
>${record.custrecord_test_customer}<#else>{}</#if>(myOptionalVar.foo)?? 
    </td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, <#if myOptionalVar?? 
    >${record.custrecord_test_address}<#else>{}</#if>(myOptionalVar.foo)?? 
</td> 
    <td>(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, <#if myOptionalVar?? 
>${record.custrecord_test_hours}<#else>{}</#if>(myOptionalVar.foo)??</td> 
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, <#if myOptionalVar?? 
>${record.custrecord_test_rate}<#else>{}</#if>(myOptionalVar.foo)??</td> 
    </td>
<td>(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, <#if myOptionalVar?? 
>${record.custrecord_job_key_test}<#else>{}</#if>(myOptionalVar.foo)??</td> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, <#if myOptionalVar?? 
>${record.custrecord_test_list_record}<#else>{}</#if>(myOptionalVar.foo)?? 
    </td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr></table>
</body>
</pdf></#list></#if></pdfset>
```

Comment: `<#if .locale == "zh_CN">` is wrong. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I understand that section is about different display/language, but honestly, I didn't write that section, the template editor automatically adds it.

Comment: By the way, now it is telling me I need a closing table row tag at line:

    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">